# Tranforms from torchvision is not working?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

[image: Extract for Q]

My line of code is

`from torchvision import transforms simple_tranform=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224,224)),tranforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize([0.485,0.456,0.406],[0.229,0.224,0.225])])`

```
Yet it shows me an error of NameError: name 'tranforms' is not defined I don't understand why as this is my first time using it
```

Many thanks

I tried googling it and followed all the advice but it didn't work. I expected it to work.

Comment: I believe there is a typo, it's transforms, not tranforms :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```py
..., tranforms.ToTensor(), ...
```

Should be

```py
..., transforms.ToTensor(), ...
```